# Click function interfering with hrefs

Tags: jquery, html, click, href

The following code is interfering with all my html href statements

```
$(
function(){
    // Get a reference to the content div (into which we will load content).
    var jContent = $( "#simplecart_items" );

    // Hook up link click events to load content.
    $( "a" ).click(function( e ){
            var jLink = $( this );

            // Override the click to load the contents at URL.
            jContent.load( jLink.attr( "href" ) );

            // Prevent default click.
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    );

}
```

);

Interfering with:

```
<ul class="one-row social">
<li class="updown-container"><a href="http://instagram.com/Blah" target="_blank"     class="updown icon-instagram"></a></li>
</ul>
```

Can someone help me out as to why and possibly how to fix this? i've been trying things for an hour..

Comment: What do you mean with "Interfering"? What do you expect?

Comment: Can you post the html you want to attach the listener?

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing it's:

```
// Prevent default click.
e.preventDefault();
```

Answer (score 0):

You're telling it to effect every 'a' element.

I'm guessing you only want to effect 'a' elements inside some other element, say '#cart'.

If so, Change:

```
$( "a" ).click(function( e ){
```

To:

```
$( "#cart a" ).click(function( e ){
```

Comment: Ahh it's still not working.. with your change I can now click on my href links however the above code doesn't work.. it's basically suppose to load content within a DIV as opposed to refreshing the page.. I guess i'll keep trying different things.. thanks for the input though!!

Answer (score 0):

The url which you are trying to load content in from does not allow AJAX access.

Here is the code, better written and working:

```
var jContent = $("#simplecart_items");

$(".social").find('a').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    jContent.load($(this).attr("href"));

});
```

Load Error: *XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://instagram.com/Blah. Origin null is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Origin.*

jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/k82hR/